# How to select part of a string value that comes before a space

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a field that contains a string value but there are spaces inside the string. This value represent an example of the field value:

```
XXXX-XXX-111111-2222-33 SSS x=AAAA     Au=AAAA  QQQ=AAA(222) SS=AAAA
```

How can I query the part that is before the first space in this field? which is in our example:

```
XXXX-XXX-111111-2222-33
```

So if the field name `f` and table `t`, I will query:

```
SELECT f from t;
```

How to query part of the string that comes before the space?

**NOTE:**

The spaces can be one or more space. Please consider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`f`, SPACE(1), 1)
FROM `t`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff2d3a3eec275b7ac33d3cc91fc1c3d8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTRING()` and `POSITION()` to do it,`POSTION()` is used to find the index for the first white space,and `SUBSTRING()` is used to find the required substring

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD',1,
      POSITION(' ' IN 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD')) AS result;
```

Output:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

More readable way:

```
SET @str='ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD';
SELECT SUBSTR(@str,1,POSITION(' ' IN @str)) AS result;
```